# How can I add a query in Ajax code with the parameter data passed?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am doing a project in laravel with a create form in ajax. I need to join two tables after the form is done, so in ajax code because I need to take some selection. Here there is the ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
      data: $('#hourForm').serialize(),
      url: "{{ route('others.store') }}",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
          var name = <?php DB::select('SELECT projects.nameP from projects, data where projects.id = data.project_id?>
          var hour = '<tr id="hour_id_' + data.id + '"><td>' + data.day + '</td><td>'+ data.project_id+'</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + data.nHours + '</td><td>' + data.notesH + '</td>';
```

And here the form:

```
<form id="hourForm" name="hourForm" class="form-horizontal">
       <input type="hidden" name="hour_id" id="hour_id">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="day" class="col-sm-2 control-label">DATA</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="day" name="day" value="" required="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Progetto</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <select name="project_id" id="project_id">
                    <option value="" selected disabled hidden><b>Scegli un'opzione</b></option>
                        @foreach($projects as $project)
                            <option value="{{$project->id}}">{{$project->nameP}}</option>   
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nHours" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ore</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nHours" name="nHours" value="" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="notesH" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Note</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="notesH" name="notesH" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" value="create">Aggiungi
         </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I don't know how to replace data that is only the variable in ajax function. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You cannot run PHP code inside a javascript. PHP only runs on the server and javascript runs in the browser.

Comment: You have to think of the PHP code you call in AJAX like a remove function library. That query should be in the page `route('others.store')`

Comment: That PHP should do the query and package the result up as JSON and echo it back. The Success function will then receive that data in its param `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to perform such a query inside your javascript.

Why don't you perform the query within the `route('others.store')`? I believe that its calling a controller's function so: just run that join back there and bring the `name` along with the rest of the data.

Comment: I tried to do that but i face a Internal Server Error,

`public function store(Request $request){
        $hourID = $request->hour_id;
        $name = DB::select('SELECT projects.nameP from projects, hours WHERE projects.id=hours.project_id AND projects.id = ?', $request->project_id);
        $hour = Hour::updateOrCreate(['id' => $hourID, 'nameP'=>$name[0]->nameP], ['project_id' => $request->project_id, 'day'=>$request->day, 'nHours' => $request->nHours, 'notesH' =>$request->notesH]);
        return Response::json($hour);
    }`

Comment: Also, is this join being performed over your project's database? You could use Eloquent instead and it would be easier (just saying).

Comment: message: "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/PROGETTO2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 333"

Comment: I don't know how to modify, I don't have any idea

Comment: I think that some value in that `select` is an array and it is trying to read it as an string, which won't work.